# Android - need to implement two switches that can turn each other on and off

Tags: java, android, user-interface, widget, logic

I have two switches A and B. Thus far I can get it so that when A is **on**, and I tap on it, it can go to **off**, and switch B to **on**. But if I try to initiate A to **on**, or B to **on** from **off**, then I can't do it. Is there a simple elegant way in which they both can talk to each other. I have already used `onCheckChanged` and `onClickListener` to implement a logic for this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used onCheckChanged and it worked just fine. You just use `setChecked(boolean)`

Here's my example:
[image: MainActivity.java]

[image: activity_main.xml]

Comment: Thank you, this is a simple way of doing it.

Comment: But , You Will Get In Infinite Loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use radioButtons . Here's [a link](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)